# SQL aggregate in a custom way

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query on SQL Server Grouping. Using SQL Server 2012.

We have a couple of tables - say Orders and Order Details (1..* relationship).
Suppose the Orders table has the following cols:
`OrderID`,`OrderDate`
and OrderDetails has
`OrderID`, `OrderDetailID`, `ProductID`, `IsGift` (Has Y, N values), `GiftAmt`
How can I query these tables to get all the Orders along with a HasGift column that will be Y if at least one OrderDetail has IsGift=Y in that Order, Otherwise HasGift will be N.

For e.g.

```
OrderID  Date
1        2020-05-06
2        2020-06-22
3        2020-07-02
```

```
OrderID  OrderDetailID    ProductID    IsGift     GiftAmt
1        1                123          N          NULL
1        2                356          N          NULL
2        1                335          Y          10
2        2                993          N          NULL
3        1                377          Y          10
3        2                453          N          NULL
3        3                343          Y          50
3        4                565          N          NULL
```

```
Expected o/p:
OrderID    OrderDate    HasGift     GiftSum 
1          2020-05-06   N           NULL
2          2020-06-22   Y           10
3          2020-07-02   Y           60
```

Comment: how did you get `60` ?

Comment: Why is `OrderID = 3` in the details table but not in the details table?  Something seems amiss with your data model.

Comment: oops - corrected the expected output. 10 for #2 and 60 for #3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT o.OrderID, 
       o.Date AS OrderDate
       COALESCE(MAX(od.IsGift), 'N') AS HasGift,
       SUM(od.GiftAmt) AS GiftSum
FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN OrderDetails od 
     ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID AND od.IsGift = 'Y'
GROUP BY o.OrderID, o.Date
```